# Is it possible to get krbtgt hash from TGT ticket?

Tags: encryption, windows, decryption, kerberos, kerberoasting

As you know, during a kerberoasting attack, we can intercept the TGS ticket and use brute force tools (john the ripper, hashcat) to find out the password of the service accounts that signed the TGS tickets.

Is it possible to do the same for TGT tickets, thus knowing the krbtgt password?

I tried to experiment and set up RC4 encryption for TGT tickets using group policies.

After that, I tried using kirbi2john to convert the TGT and using the dictionary brute force method to find out the password. It didn’t work out for me, although I knew the krbtgt password in advance.

Is it possible theoretically or practically?